# Error while using Hadoop Partitioning

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

This is what I am doing:

```
public class MOPartition extends Partitioner<Text, Text> {
        public MOPartition() {}
...
}
```

Error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   globalSort$MOPartition.()

Even defining a empty constructor didnt help.

I then Googled it and came across following link http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/preserve-JobTracker-information-td826974.html. I then checked my JRE version and it is 1.6.0.26. So, I think I am pretty much safe as far JRE is concerned.

Can you please suggest what can be the issue?

Comment: First: What are you doing? OR what have you done to get this error?

Comment: I just figured out the error. It was missing "static" declaration. I am quite new to Java, thats why didnt knew its importance.

Comment: @Piyush:  You could increase the value of this question for others that have the same problem by 1) making the question more specific, 2) providing the relevant code surrounding the initial problem, and 3) providing the corrected code.  I'm afraid that anyone that stumbles across this question at this point won't get specific solutions to the problem.

Comment: @DonBranson: I actually forgot to put the code in code block, probably thats the reason you were not able to figure out the code. I have now edited it.